# Full text search on iOS

Tags: ios, full-text-search

What is best practices to implement full text search on iOS? I have a database with about 400.000 entries. The data structure is not fixed, could be SQLite or Core Data or any other data structure which you would recommend.

Are there any existing frameworks? I do not want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: What do you mean by "full text search"? Are you looking for finding substrings in a string? If so, then `- [NSString rangeOfString:]` may be what you want.

Comment: You don't want to search this way through strings, will be much to slow. There are techniques to improve full-text search, but I don't know any technology for iOS.